# Hive - Select query returns 1 or 0 based on lookup table values

Tags: hive, hiveql

In Select query I need to return `1` or `0` based on another lookup table values.

**Table1:**

```
Column1 Column2
S       0
```

**Table2:**

```
Column1
A
F
S
```

Table1 Column1 value `S` is available in Table2 Column1 value, so I want to return `1` in select query.

How do i write a SELECT query like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Table2.Column1, if(!isnull(Table1.Column1), 1, 0)
  from Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1;
```

Output:

```
A       0
F       0
S       1
```

Comment: Thanks!! it helped.